# Can't align 5 items in a row using autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am struggling to align 5 items in a row using auto layout as shown in the storyboard.

[image]

I can align the 3 items highlighted below but the 2 inbetween just don't want to align.

[image]

I have tried pinning the items to the buttons next to each of the items and setting the size but they refuse to align properly. Have also tried setting the 2 misplaced buttons to the leading and trialing container as shown below but these still do not align properly (or even closely).

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What constraint are you using to try to align them?

Comment: What kind of alignment are you trying to achieve? You want their vertical centers to align?

Comment: I am trying to align them horizontally as shown in the images above (those are off the storyboard but on a device the two buttons are misaligned.

Comment: @rdelmar been trying trailing and leading alignment to the container or aligning them to the buttons next to each other. The big button is horizontally aligned to the container.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "alignment".  Are you trying to have equal horizontal spaces between the 5 views?

Comment: @rdelmar ah yes thats exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is with spacer views. You need to add a UIView between each of your views and give them each horizontal spacing constraints to the view on either side. You'll need to edit these constraints so they are between the spacer's leading or trailing edge, and the view's centerX (the constant value should be 0). Give the spacers equal widths (but no fixed width), a fixed height, and a clear background color. You views on the left and right sides should have constraints to their closest edge, but the center view shouldn't have a centerX constraint (it's not needed). This will cause the views to be equally spaced in all screen sizes, and in both orientations.

Comment: Oh autolayout is fun! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to create another superview (UIView) within which your button items are located. Then you can align your buttons more fluidly within that superview that encapsulates only those buttons rather than just wrestling with the constraints within the card superview, which it seems you are doing. Just make the background of that UIView clear, place the buttons on it, and it will appear exactly the same and you'll have a better way to anchor your views. This could also come in handy when you're targeting the functionality of just those buttons so you can grab them from the subviews of the button bar superview.